# What does the inverse Fourier transform of a constant non-zero function look like.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Worded another way, what does it look like to have all frequencies present at the same amplitude?

Comment: Dirac distribution (times constant).

Comment: Answer can be found on the [first page of Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=fourier+transform+table&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&aq=f&oq=fourier+transform+table&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l2.14665&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: My question in google, as worded, does not give the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Dirac delta (details depending on which convention you use).

Comment: Intuitively you can understand the Dirac delta "function" as a infinitely high and infinitely narrow peak at the origin with and area=1. 

The moral of the story is that the fourier transform of something broad is narrow and vice versa.